# sonarqube 4.1.2: unable to evict preview database

Tags: https, sonarqube

After performing a successful analysis, we are seeing a failure `"Unable to evict preview database: /batch_bootstrap/evict?project=10020"`.  This is followed by the summary:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Unable to evict preview database: /batch_bootstrap/evict?project=10020: Fail to execute request [code=400, url=https://XXX/batch_bootstrap/evict?project=10020]: Fail to download [https://XXX/batch_bootstrap/evict?project=10020]. Response code: 400 -> [Help 1]

This is running on SLES11SP1, Java 1.7, maven 3.3.  I've tried increasing memory (MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8092m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m") and changing ulimit for files (8192) but have not seen any change in failure.
```

Any hints?  What is the code 400?

Answer (score 0):

You should publish the properties files with the analysis configuration, and the log file complete. 
Regards.